# How te reduce the bundle size of a small Nuxt.js app

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I recently started creating a new Vue.js app with Nuxtjs. I truly love the capabilities that it has right out of the box, but size of the app is quite large. Even when I create a completely new app with `npx create-nuxt-app` and only include Vuetify and dotenv is the size of this new app more than 1MB!

[image: Initial bundle size]

Changing `'@nuxtjs/vuetify` to `['@nuxtjs/vuetify', { treeShake: true }]` does not seem to make a difference and adding `extractCSS: true` to the build property decreases the size of vedors.app from >600kb to <300kb. This is a big improvement, but the final bundle size is still really large. Especially because I did not add anything since `npx create-nuxt-app`, so the site has only 2 pages (index and inspire).

[image: New bundle size]

My question is, how can I decrease the bundle size, and more specifically:

1. how can I remove unused Vuetify components
2. Remove unused core-js/modules
3. Find other modules that are not used and remove them from the build package

Comment: `treeShake` is already true by default, so that's why there's no difference when you set it to true. And Nuxt already configures `vuetify-loader` to only bundle used components. Which components do you think are unused?

Comment: Thank you for your response! That explains the lack of difference between bundle sizes. :) There are many different packages in `core-js/modules`, since it is a mostly empty project practically none of these packages like `es6.regexp.replace` are used. Or are they used internally for Nuxt?

Comment: Nuxt depends on Vue, which uses Babel, which requires `core-js` for polyfills (it's needed in your bundle if you want to support older browsers). Nuxt should already be removing dead code from the production build, so if the code is in the production bundle, it's probably required. If you can identify something that isn't needed/optimized, we could troubleshoot further.

Comment: Extract css reduced js file size but it will generate extra css file which will be imported by the .js file. So same result

Comment: Had to import icons with config and delete old settings in nuxt config.

Comment: How did you get that nice bundle size map (attached picture) for nuxtjs?

Comment: @CoreyOsman, Apologies for my late response. This bundle size map gets generated when you add `analyze: true` to the `build` section of nuxt.config.js.